# How to show multiple items from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am building a blog using html and php and have run into a problem with my sql. In my blog I would like to show all the comments that have been put in by users in the comments section that have the same article ID. In my database I am saving these parameters via $_POST and a query ID, ArticleID, Comments. However only the last comment that has been inserted in the database with that articleID is showing up.

this is the code that I am using. Can anyone help me please?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST["comment"]);
    $articleID = $_GET['artId'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_comments (comment, ArticleID) VALUES  ('$comment', $articleID)";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
}

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE ArticleID = $artId";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $articleId = $row['ArticleID'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];             
}

if(isset($comment))
{
    echo "<div class='comments'>";
    if (isset($comment))
    {
        echo "<div class='commentName'>";
        echo $comment;
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
 $articleId = $row['ArticleID'];
 $comment = $row['comment'];                
}
```

to:

```
$comment = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    $comment .= $row['comment'] . '<br/>';
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help that worked :) sry I cant vote up its my first time posting :(

Comment: is there any way I can make the div repeat for every comment?

Comment: @user3697612 yes, check how tag BR is appended, the same way you can use div, but this site is not about learning php